# How do I make a glowing image texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, light

I'm trying to make an image texture that glows in Blender. An example might be a television or a smart phone. How can I accomplish this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

I haven't rendered the image, but this seems to do the effect that I wanted:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a plane, unwrap it and give it an image texture. Set the nodes as pictured below (connect the *Image Texture* node to *Emission* node). Set up the emitter's strenght.

[image]

If you want to increase the glowing effect you may do this in **Compositor**. Just add a *Glare* node and experiment with its settings.

[image]

Comment: I'm brand new to this forum, but I edited my post with a screenshot of the nodes (which looks a lot like your first image), but the edits aren't visible yet because it hasn't been peer reviewed. Thank you and thank you Ross, couldn't have done it without your help!

Answer (score 1):

Set your image texture, and set your material type to "emission".

**edit** if you're using cycles:

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details of the settings with a screenshot?

Comment: OP is unclear which render engine is being used.

Comment: @RossM. You can do screengrabs on blender pressing Ctrl+F3

Comment: ... did ... you take a picture... of your screen?