# How to create a fire/light effect in a spaceship engine

Tags: rendering, animation, materials

I was wondering how I could create this effect in blender for an animation:

[image]

[image]

How can I make this bloom effect?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31262/how-do-i-make-a-glowing-image-texture, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender.

Comment: Yes, but I'm still not sure how to make this particular effect

Comment: I would create the basic shape with a mesh and use volumetric emission, then add some glare and glow in the compositor.

Answer (score 13):

When dealing with these effects, generally you have 2 ways - create some geometry with high amount of lighting and use [volumetrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_lighting) for them or fake these effects with compositor.

**Using volumetric materials**

You should have some geometry providing actual rays of light; this may be some basic mesh which has forms of rays, or particles emitted from somewhere, forming cloud of light. Then with using volume materials you'll get desired effect.

To begin, either model basic form of rays as mesh as @PGmath suggested or create particles system on the object, which is supposed to emit light, and render those particles as volumetric halos with using Point Density texture which is what I did. See [What is Point Density](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46717/what-is-a-point-density-texture?lq=1) for more info about this feature. See [Halo particles don't render in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45481/halo-particles-dont-render-in-cycles) for details about texture setup (*Note: accessible starting from Blender 2.76*).

1. Add a [particle system](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/physics/particles/introduction.html) to the object, with vertex groups point it to be emitted from adjacent place (via *Vertex Group* rollout in particle system's settings). Set up a force field / emission direction for particles to form basic shape of the rays. You might want to disable gravity for particles to stop them falling down while being emitted.
2. Create several cubes which will contain particles inside. They will serve as domains for volumetric materials. I added particles coming from the floor too, for adding a bit of volumetric lighting across the scene.

   [image: positioning objects in the scene]

   Also you may want to position illuminating objects on different layers; this could improve scene allowing to:

   - overlay objects that illuminate scene while post-processing; this can save render times quite a bit.
   - control reflections / refractions if needed. See [Post-processing Lightsabers in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/post-processing-lightsabers-in-blender) for more info.
3. In material setup for the domains add *Texture* > *Point Density* and *Shader* > *Emission* shader which will be connected to *Volume* output socket of *Material Output* node. Set *Point Density* to *Particle System* mode and choose adjacent one. You may want to add *Math* node in order to control amount of final effect.

   [image: point density domain setup]
4. Play animation to let particles emit. After rendering and a bit of post-processing you'll get something like glow where particles are located.

   [image: somewhat result with point density]

**Faking effect in compositor**

While you will get nice result with volumetric material it's very heavy for rendering. And since you asked about animation the rendering times may be even more important. Hence it may be worth trying to fake it with post-processing (at least, part of effect). From this point of view, I think [How to render lightning in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21739/how-to-render-lightning-in-cycles) is related with only exception for actual object.
In case of this scene, I used following steps:

1. Model the objects, apply emissive material for adjacent parts. Render the image.
2. In *Composite* nodes with keying get part of image which is going to be heavily processed. Create a mask which will control where post-processing will occur. Overlay them together.

   [image: node setup for faking glow in this particular case]

The Post-processing group is the one used in the first way and it was used for refining the result (adding *Glare*, *Sunbeams*, vignette, desaturation of some parts of image and *Lens Distortion*).

Final result:

[image: somewhat final result with compositing only]

The rendering is ~ 15 times less.

There's a lot of room for improving:

- if considering caustics in render it may be a bit more [complicated to setup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/post-processing-lightsabers-in-blender);
- the result with volumetric materials lacks gradient fade out and consistence of light; result with compositing has too short rays etc.

It may depend on the actual scene requirements / limitations.

Answer (score 8):

I used this setup with a bunch of cones and a Volume Emission material
You can parent them to an empty and scale it with noise, to create flickering effect. Or even better parrent to few Empties and create separate flickering effect

[image]

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41190

[image]

Comment: ofcourse Glowing is needed, but that's a compositing  easy piece

Comment: can you please migrate your linked file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? Links in pasteall expire after some time and then your answer will be incomplete.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3112" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3112/)   File migrated

Answer (score 2):

I tried simply using volumetrics with no compositor tricks to get something similar to your first picture. This is what I ended up with: 
[image]

This is my node setup: [image]

It involves adding a quadratic sphere gradient to determine the strength of an emissive volume material. There are two spheres in this scene[image]