# Creating an edgeless material for flame

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I'm looking to recreate something like this [image], but if possible, using just the nodes editor and a mesh. I'm primarily having trouble with finding the right combination of nodes to create that edgeless, or feathered look to the mesh. The rest should be simple enough to do, mixing it in with transparent and emission shaders. I think I have that part of the node setup ready to go, but I need to have the rest of the node setup to be sure. That's where I'm hoping someone here might come in.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48816/how-to-create-a-fire-light-effect-in-a-spaceship-engine and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender

Comment: Volumetric emission is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea..

You could just draw with really soft brush in Photoshop/Gimp, something similar to a flame. Then use that as the mask factor.

[image] 
[image]

I just did this on a flat plane. If you use a solid object just make sure all the sides are close to each other or it might look a little weird.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try the fresnel node, which is white where normals are at oblique angles (to the camera/viewport), and black when normals are face-on. You can use that as a mix factor for your alpha channel or transparent shader, and so give your mesh soft edges.

Answer (score -2):

Coloramp to Emission shader and Quick smoke gave me this result:[image]

Add more smoke for stronger effect