# Simple method for adding spaceship engine exhaust and glow

Tags: particles

I want to add some engine exhaust and glow from my spaceships. I have read through this answer: [How to create a fire/light effect in a spaceship engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48816/how-to-create-a-fire-light-effect-in-a-spaceship-engine)

I must admit that this method is way beyond my capabilities at this time. Is there now a simpler way with Blender 2.80 or a good video you Guys could suggest that would allow me to create this effect? Thanks

Danny

Comment: Do you want to use particles? Because it's the tag you've used

Comment: Yes. From what I have read, particles would be the best choice? Thanks