# Fire + Smoke Loaded Question

Tags: rendering, animation, smoke-simulation, fire, mantaflow

I have a scene where I'm launching cans that have an exhaust port like a rocket or a firework that shoots fire and smoke out of it as its launching. I'm having several issues. First time using this simulation. It seems to be pretty inconsistent at times. Following instructions from YouTube videos exactly, inputting the exact same values on the same properties and some how achieve different results. Viewport doesn't render sometimes.

List of Issues :

1. I'd like to create a long clean steady flame like a jet engine but
   with colorful smoke. [image]
2. I'd like each flame to be different colored along with different colored smoke. Don't know how to achieve this with them all being in the same domain. Would I have to create separate individual domains for all the cans?[image]
3. I'd like the smoke and flame to dissipate earlier not sure where to control that.
4. Blender seems to run really slow for me. I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong but when I watch other people on YouTube there's seems to be a lot more smooth. Mine is very choppy when just navigating in Viewport Solid. I have a pretty good computer as well.
   -AMD RYZEN 9 3950X 16-Core Processor 3.5-Ghz    -64GB of RAM    -nVida GEFORCE RTX 2080Ti 11GB

Any tips? suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don‘t trust yt videos. They often accelerate the videos so it just looks quicker 

Comment: For the YT videos: trust what Chris says, that's not always what it is in real life. Especially with smoke simulations things can get a little choppy quickly. For your simulation: your screenshot is really bad quality to read all the settings, but apart from quality - more interesting would be your domain settings. I have some ideas but I'm not sure yet. The bottom part of your domain looks like the simulation is messed up, I sometimes experience this because of vorticity settings and the _Adaptive Domain_ etc.

Comment: Oh, and for a "long clean steady flame like a jet engine" it would be better to model it with an emissive volume material, one example you can find here in the first answer: [How to create a fire/light effect in a spaceship engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49330/99859) and combine this with a smoke simulation.

Comment: @Chris - Awesome! Appreciate it

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - Thank you! I changed a couple of things and still not getting the result I want.  It looks more like its bellowing thick smoke rather than large fire.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - I added more images to the post. Shows my current settings. Also having a rendering issue where I want the simulation to start later on in the scene for example I want it to start at 150 which is does but random frames from before will show some distortions such a "leaks" in the domain or something or the smoke would start to rise and fill the scene.