# Is there an Emit option for a texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes, light

I've tried checking indirect lighting and selecting approximate in the world settings, then put emit on high in the materials tab, but the glow itself is very very weak. Is there a way to adjust the glow distance? Thanks!

---

*Update*: I've actually been successful with this by adding a glare node and selecting fog glow, then adjust the threshold, and emitting it to max in the materials tab. The only problem I have with this is that my model's texture looks really bright. I have a Godzilla model, it comes with two textures. one for the whole entire body, then a separate glowing texture specifically for the spikes.

What i did was I selected the material, added the body texture, then added the spikes glow texture. I then added the glare node, but when I got to emit and set it to 2.00, the whole body texture glows. I just want that spike glow texture to glow.

**Is there an emit option, just for a texture?**

Comment: Also see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing/35860#35860 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31262/how-do-i-make-a-glowing-image-texture

Comment: Those are in Cycles. I'm in Blender Internal.

Comment: can someone please answer?