# How to add a Bloom effect to this scene?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, effects

[image: rendered scene]

I want the windows to have a bloom effect around them, like this:

[image: example of desired effect]

I've looked around online, and people have said using the following node setup created the effect, but it doesn't work for me.

[.BLEND](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzgDIjhDOu6EaHFSUlRSQnlXc00)

[image: compositor nodes]

Comment: Use a glare node and set the threshold level according to the brightness values on the scene. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54168/any-way-to-control-light-halos-in-the-compositor-based-on-emission-level/54173#54173

Comment: this has been asked numerous times. you can use the search box on the  top right right of the page. http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=glow+compositor

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31262/how-do-i-make-a-glowing-image-texture

Comment: @PaulGonet I have tried the techniques outlined in that Post, it does not work.

Comment: @cegaton I have tried the techniques outlined in those posts as well, they do not work. I have compositor nodes enabled and set up correctly.

Comment: As above, use Glare. Hopefully this will help http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/65728/29586